# How to Create a Large 3d Space Inside a Small Object?

Tags: modeling

I need to create a display screen that appears to have real 3d depth inside of it. Picture the effect from the game Portal - or looking into a tea cup and seeing a full sized world, but not seeing it if you look at the teacup from the side or bottom.

In this case the screen has to be thin, meaning that if you look at it from the side you should not be able to see the objects 'inside' the screen as they exist in 3d space.

I'm at a total loss and have a deadline coming up soon so any helps is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of effect is more easily done with game engines that support non euclidean worlds (eg Unity or Unreal Engine) and/or custom camera textures. In Blender it can only be done with compositing tricks and IMO is a hassle to do well (compared to the other methods).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's say that your portal is this oval, you could for example use the *Holdout* option of the object so that it creates a hole in it. Render your animation. Now remove the oval and the other objects of your scene, keep the same camera movement and this time shoot the world that is beyond the portal. Then just mix the two footages in the *Compositor* or in the *Video Sequencer*. To have transparency don't forget to enable the *Transparent* option in the *Render panel > Film*.

[image]

Comment: While I'd like to think what I'm imagining is possible in a more dynamic way it would seem as this is the best option that is being presented. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can achieve that effect in an easy way by using a glossy material for the screen and placing all the 3D world objects out of camera view:

[image]

For configuring the glossy material you can follow this great video by
*The CG Essentials*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLChjoLf5jg

Comment: Thanks Alberto - unfortunately there is a steering wheel in front of the screen which I do not want to appear 'in' the 3d world inside the screen.